# urllib.request.urlretrieve ERROR trying to download jpeg in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urlretrieve

I am trying to download a .jpg file, using **urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)** in Python 3.5.2. The url is http://dm.victoriassecret.com/product/404x539/V603923_CROP1.jpg . The following error raises: 
**http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response**.

I also have a problem when trying the same with this url = [http://lp2.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2017/9AS 0505882 002 00 0034.jpg],type[STILLLIFE_FRONT]&hmver=0&call=url[file:/product/style]](http://lp2.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2017/9AS%200505882%20002%2000%200034.jpg],type[STILLLIFE_FRONT]&hmver=0&call=url[file:/product/style]) .

In that case the following error raises: **raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version not supported**

Does anybody know what is the problem with these urls and how could I fix it? Sharing your knowledge with me, would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remote isn't responding because you're lacking headers in your request.
Furthermore, I suggest you use the `requests` module (install it via `pip install requests`), as it's way better and faster than `urllib`:

```
import requests
headers = headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}

pic = requests.get('http://dm.victoriassecret.com/product/404x539/V603923_CROP1.jpg', headers=headers)

with open('beautiful.jpg', 'wb') as photo:
    photo.write(pic.content)
```

Now open your working directory and you'll find the image residing there.

This will also work with your other link.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I started using requests as you recommended.